# login persistence in browser req.user (node.js, mean.io)

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm following with tutorial "Building AngularJS and Node.js Apps with the MEAN Stack", and just stuck with 
"04. Persisting Login between Page Refreshes.mp4"

As said in this part of tutorial, some middleware function must console.log req.user object. But it is not happening.

package.json's dependencies:

```
"body-parser": "~1.0.2",
"cookie-parser": "^1.1.0",
"express": "~4.1.2",
"express-session": "^1.1.0",
"jade": "~1.3.1",
"mongoose": "~3.8.9",
"morgan": "~1.0.1",
"passport": "^0.2.0",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"serve-favicon": "~2.0.0",
"stylus": "~0.44.0"
```

server.js (full)

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;



var config = require('./server/config/config')[env];
require('./server/config/express')(app, config);
require('./server/config/mongoose')(config);
var User = mongoose.model('User');


passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  User.findOne({username: username}).exec(function(error, user) {

    if(error) { return done(error); }

    if(user && user.authenticate(password)) {
      return done(null, user);
    } else {
      return done(null, false);
    }
  });
}));

// !!!! this middleware must console.log req.user, but it is always undefined.
// req.session displays and seems like correct
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//  console.log(req.session);
  console.log(req.user);
  next();
});


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  if(user) {
    done(null, user._id);
  }
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findOne({_id: id}).exec(function(error, user) {
    if(!user) {
      return done(null, false);
    }
    return done(null, user);
  });
});




require('./server/config/routes')(app);


app.listen(config.port);
console.log('listening on port ' + config.port + '...');
```

express.js (full)

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var stylus = require('stylus');
var logger = require('morgan');
var body_parser = require('body-parser');
var cookie_parser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');


module.exports = function(app, config) {
  app.set('views', config.root_path + '/server/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');

  function compile(str, path){
    return stylus(str).set('filename', path);
  }
  app.use(stylus.middleware({
    src: config.root_path + '/public',
    compile: compile
  }));

  app.use(logger());
  app.use(cookie_parser('multi vision unicorns'));
  app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', key: 'sid', cookie: { secure: true }}));
  app.use(body_parser());
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(express.static(config.root_path + '/public'));
  app.use(favicon(config.root_path + '/public/favicon.ico'));



// development
// =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =
  if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
    app.locals.pretty = true;
  }

};
```

Right now I can log in using passport module via POST, but after refreshing page, state of login does not persist, and I have to log in again. In tutorial said, that this middleware

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.user);
  next();
});
```

must console.log user object even after refreshing page. But in does not.

The ending goal of lesson, is to persist state of login for browser, so that field 'username', 'password', button 'Sign In' were hidden after logging in, and stayed hidden after refreshing. But seems like server does not persist state of login too. May be problem with session, may be something else.

Please help..

=   =   =   =   =   =   =   =

Problem solved, - had to remove "cookie: { secure: true }" part from:
"app.use(session({ secret: 'secret', key: 'sid', cookie: { secure: true }}));" as it works [only with https](https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookie-options)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to store the session. (Example in [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org).)

```
session = require 'express-session'
mongoStore = (require 'connect-mongo') session

app.use session
  secret: 'super secret'
  store: new mongoStore(db: 'session')
  cookie:
    secure: true
    maxAge: 2592000000
```

Comment: I tried that, installed connect-mongo, but there was no effect to my code. I'm sure, this variant should work with some slight amend, but right now I have no idea what to fix.
In tutorial, author did not use connect-mongo, so may be there are some other solution for storing session?